# Delete file in windows 7 using VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, delete-file

I have written following code in vb.net to delete the file.

```
If File.Exists(strPath & "\ReportEng.ini") = True Then
File.SetAttributes(strPath & "\ReportEng.ini", FileAttributes.Normal)
File.Delete(strPath & "\ReportEng.ini")
End If
File.Copy("\\192.168.0.1\SAP_Shared\AddonExtra\ReportEng.ini", strPath & "\ReportEng.ini")
```

This code works perfectly in windows xp. But in Windows 7,I can not delete it. This OS is hectic OS from developer's point of view. Some or other problem occurs and Microsoft has not considered the developer while building this OS.

How do I delete file in Windows 7 ?

Comment: What sort of error do you get?

Comment: If you're deleting the file, why are you setting the attributes? Is the file "in use" when you try to delete it?

Comment: If `strPath` is anything like `c:\program files\...`, then yeah, Windows 7 needs special permissions to mess with those files.  If that's the case, consider using one of the SpecialFolder paths instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to delete the file: there is an overload [File.Copy Method (String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) which allows overwriting.

You didn't say what error you get. I suspect it is because the user doesn't have write access to the directory. You should probably be using a subdirectory of the directory returned by  `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` or maybe `.LocalApplicationData`, and definitely not the directory containing the program.

Also, using `Path.Combine(strPath, "ReportEng.ini")` is how you're meant to combine paths - it'll take care of, e.g., the trailing path separator for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's so easy to do so;

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\somefile.ext") Then 'Check whether file exists
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\somefile.ext") 'Delete the file!
End If
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

The preferred method for interfacing with the Windows file system uses the following namespace:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem
```

To delete a file:

```
Dim FileLocation As String = strPath & "\ReportEng.ini"
If Not GetDirectoryInfo(FileLocation).Exists Then
  GetFileInfo(FileLocation).Delete()
End If
```

Comment: This is a cowardly down vote. Explain your reason so we can all learn.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but you got down-voted because it's System.IO and you use the File class in that namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx